# Nested Dictionaries in an empty dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
list1 = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
list2 = ['a','b','c']
list3 = ['A','B']
main_list = [{k: dict(zip(list2, sub))} for k,sub in zip(list3, list1)]
print(main_list)
```

I am trying to work on this code, my goal is to write a dictionary within a nested dictionary. So, basically I'm trying to add the content in the main_list inside an empty dictionary. I'm hoping to get this ouput shown below:

```
{{'A':{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}, {'B':{'a':4, 'b':5, 'c',6}}}
```

Please help:(

Comment: Dictionary has by definition `key` and `value` - so the most outer brackets are impossible to obtain, unless you mean it to be `set` (which graphically would be represented by the same brackets)

Comment: Should the outer `{}` be `[]` in your expected output?

Comment: Addition to @GrzegorzSkibinski's point, even if you meant `set` you can't create such thing because the items in the `set` has to be hashable. `dict`s are not hashable so it is impossible.

Comment: Also - count your brackets, there's one too many on the left

Comment: The outer should be : {}

Comment: For the simple form - I suspect this is what you're looking for: `main_list = dict(zip(list3, [dict(zip(list2, el)) for el in list1]))`

Comment: Maybe what you want is `{'A':{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}, 'B':{'a':4, 'b':5, 'c',6}}`?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution:

```
main_dict = {k: v for i, k in enumerate(list3) for v in [{c: n for c, n in zip(list2, list1[i])}]}
```

I would not call it 'main_list', given it's a dict.